# Jquery Image MouseOver Through Coordinates

Tags: jquery, mouseover, onmouseout

I am having an Floor Image in that i am using the "Usemap" attribute to link the coordinates.

Like this:

```
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="5th_floor_screen-size.jpg" width="1372" height="906" border="0" usemap="#Map" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

```
 <area class="tooltip" shape="rect" coords="1232,550,1298,621" href="#" title="Store Room" />
        <area class="tooltip" shape="rect" coords="1301,550,1351,621" href="#" title="Record Room" />
</map>
```

Now what i need is i will be having two  image like 1.Store Room 2.Record Room

for eg:

Suppose if do onmouseover on the store room the area which is in the store room should highlight and then onmouseover it should be display none and also recordroom.

How to implement this either in Jquery or  javascript?..

FYR:

As this i need...

[enter link description here](http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper/example.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this jsfiddle I made. Propably this helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/SB77y/

Comment: To run  this script what should i need

Comment: implement the script of the fiddle and customize it like you need it. change the class names to your names and it will work.